# Limit Subnodes Performance in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nosql

I am writing a cypher to get output of 5 product per category with this cypher:

```
MATCH (s:Supplier)-[:POST]->(p:Product)-[:BELONG_TO]->(c:Category) 
WITH *
MATCH r = (c)<-[:BELONG_TO*0..5]-(p)
WITH c, collect(tail(nodes(r))) AS allCatProducts
RETURN c, reduce(outputProducts=allCatProducts[..0] , catProduct IN allCatProducts | outputProducts + catProduct)[..5];
```

However, the performance of this cypher is very poor. Is there anything I did wrong here?

Also, I am trying to understand the part:

```
[:BELONG_TO*0..5]
```

and

```
(catProduct)[..5]
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to overcomplicate the query, this query should do the job :

```
MATCH (s:Supplier)-[:POST]->(p:Product)-[:BELONG_TO]->(c:Category)
RETURN c.name, collect(p)[..5] as products
```

---

Concerning your other question :

```
(x)-[r:BELONG_TO*0..5]->(y)
```

is variable length path query, but here you should be aware that if no `y` node is found, the `x` will be returned as `y`

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-match.html#_relationships_in_depth

http://graphaware.com/graphaware/2015/05/19/neo4j-cypher-variable-length-relationships-by-example.html

---

```
(collection)[..5]
```

is telling to return only the first 5 elements of the collection, collection is like a `List` in Java or `array` in php for example.